# Display tooltip on a ButtonField in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, tooltip

In BlackBerry I have placed some buttons at the bottom of the screen to display a toolbar.

I want to display a tooltip on the button when the button gets the focus and remove the tool tip when the button losses the focus. Can we add tool tip to a button in Blackberry? I don't have exact idea about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set on focus listener on your control. Check whether it has focus or not, Call status.show method (Refer [this](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Status.html))

This will look like a tool tip.

Comment: Thank You so much MobileDev123.I really appreciate it a lot.I had no idea at all that it is just a line of code.I was searching on net so much to achieve this.Thanks for the solution

Comment: Let me give you a tip: if you are planning to spend more time in Blackberry development, go to blackberry's own support forum (only because there is more activity in BB comparing to here), this type of questions are discussed frequently there. And you can get more efficient answers.